# C++ , Displaying a list of existing objects in a multiset ,given specific criteria

Tags: c++

Basically  I have a class  which represents flowers, which  has some fields  - name, is it flowering (string), family and height.

I need to implement a function that searches for all elements  that meet the criteria, which is a specific family name.
I came to the conclusion that a multi-set will be appropriate due  to the possible duplicates.

This is my code so far:

```
searchByFam(string fam,multiset<CFLowers> mySet){
    multiset<CFLowers>::iterator it;

    for (it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end(); ++it){
        mySet.find(fam);
    }
}
```

The problem with it is that the dot is getting underlined and with a mouse hover I get the following error : no instance of overloaded function matches the argument type list.
Can someone tell me what is the problem and point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Which dot ? Which IDE ? What does your compiler say about it ?

Comment: mySet.find(fam);   the dot between mySet and find obviously. IDE is VS 2013.   ,  the compiler says : no instance of overloaded function matches the argument type list.

Comment: [`std::multiset::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/find) does exist indeed. Are you sure that `CFlower` is implicitly constructible from a `std::string` ? If so, that's just Intellisense being confused.

Comment: Your argument for `find()` should be a CFLowers object.

Comment: I think I've just got confused. Seems like  
std::multiset::find   need to take CFlower object  as an argument , but i need to pass the string "fam" as a parameter so the user can  specify a family name.  Any idea what should i be using in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I came to the conclusion that a multi-set will be appropriate due to
>   the possible duplicates.

Really? The flower class will surely have duplicate `family` and `height` values but will the name ever be non unique? The "name" of the flower will most likely be the "key".

If you really do need lookup's and insertions at constant time than an associative container may be your best option, but any variations of a "multi" (set, map, etc...) is completely unnecessary.Just make sure to define your own comparison functions for sorting.

Now the problem with your code is that you haven't defined a comparison operator for your multiset, which is essential for any associative container using a user defined class.

Besides the fact you not defining a comparison operator, there exists a major error here:

```
for (it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end(); ++it){
        mySet.find(fam);
  }
```

You are calling `find` on a `multiset` which returns an iterator to the location of the first element (or an end iterator). Here, you are never actually using the declared `multiset` iterator, so you are simply trying to find the *first* occurrence of a key over and over again. What you are looking for is `std::multiset::equal_range` which returns two iterators denoting the range of elements specified by the key.

Comment: I have all the operators overloaded in the class streams , equals , and for comparison tho . Anyways I will try replacing multi-set with a set , thanks. But... from what I can understand std::set::equal_range    returns  iterators denoting the range , not the actual elements in between ,which is what i am trying to do here  ?